# How to display validation messages with javascript alert window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery-validate

I use LogOn partial view on Index view and use default LogOnModel of MVC3. But, there is not enough place to display validation messages in view. How can I display validation messages with javascript alert window?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn( LogOnModel model, string returnUrl )
{
    if ( ModelState.IsValid )
    {
        if ( ( model.UserName != null ) && ( model.Password != null ) )
        {
            if ( Membership.ValidateUser( model.UserName, model.Password ) )
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie( model.UserName, true );

                if ( Url.IsLocalUrl( returnUrl ) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith( "/" )
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith( "//" ) && !returnUrl.StartsWith( "/\\" ) )
                {
                    return Redirect( returnUrl );
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction( "Index", "Home", model );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction( "Index", "Home" );
            }
        }
        else return RedirectToAction( "Index", "Home" );
    }
    return RedirectToAction( "Index", "Home" );
}
```

In Index view:

```
 @Html.Partial( "LogOn" )
```

And LogOn view:

```
@model OnlineMarket.Models.LogOnModel
@using ( Html.BeginForm( "LogOn", "Home", FormMethod.Post ) )
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary( true )
    @Html.Hidden( "RememberMe", "true" )
    <ul class="forms">
        <li class="txt">Username</li>
        <li class="inputfield">
            @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.UserName, new { @class = "logininputs" } )
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="forms">
        <li class="txt" style="width: 26px;">Password</li>
        <li class="inputfield">
            @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.Password, new { @class = "logininputs" } )
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="forms">
        <li class="txt" style="width: 50px; margin-top: -5px; margin-left: 4px;">
            <input type="submit" value="Enter" class="buttonforinput" style="height: 23px;" />
        </li>
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: Is there not somebody help me? Any link or sample...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the unobtrusive client validation you could subscribe to the `showErrors` callback and display the errors the way you want (`alert` in your case):

```
(function ($) {
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        onsubmit: true,
        onkeyup: false,
        onfocusout: false,
        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
            if (errorList.length > 0) {
                var errors = errorList.map(function (element) {
                    return element.message;
                }).join('\r\n');
                alert(errors);
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

In order to display server side errors with `alert` on the client you shouldn't be using the `@Html.ValidationSummary( true )` helper because this helper outputs the errors directly in the view and you said that you don't have enough place.

So you could emit javascript dynamically when there are errors and display them in an `alert`:

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var errors = @Html.Raw(
            Json.Encode(
                string.Join(
                    Environment.NewLine, 
                    ViewData.ModelState
                            .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                            .SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors)
                            .Select(error => error.ErrorMessage))
                )
        );
        alert(errors);
    </script>
}
```